# Not able to tap on a Button in Table in Swift, isHittable returns False for element

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am not able to tap on a button in tableview in swift. When I record the element

`XCUIApplication().children(matching: .window)`

like this many children and finally .

```
tables.buttons["Sign Out"]
```

The element is NOT Hittable but it is Enabled. I tried to tap on it by using **pressForDuration()**, **tap()** didn't work. Please suggest a way to tap on the element.

```
Xcode version: 8.3.2
Swift:3.0
```

Comment: Try adding an accessibility identifier to the button wherever you're declaring it and re-record the test.

Comment: I am in QA team. So I don't have access to modify the source code. I have to find a work around for this. Because most of our test scripts are failing due to this issue.